# How to separate data into different column sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Column

```
+--------------------------+
|      inv_num       scn   |
+--------------------------+
|     MI1001        160008 |
|     CI1002        160008 |
|     VI1003        160008 |
+--------------------------+
```

**MI** is for Misc, **CI** is for Cargo, **VI** is for Vessel.

I need the sql result to show like

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|     scn           Misc       Cargo      Vessel |
+------------------------------------------------+
|     160008        MI1001     CI1002     VI1003 |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm new to this kind of thing so not sure how to do the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select scn,
       max(case when inv_num like 'MI%' then inv_num end) as Misc,
       max(case when inv_num like 'CI%' then inv_num end) as Cargo,
       max(case when inv_num like 'VI%' then inv_num end) as Vessel
from t
group by scn;
```

Answer (score 0):

using Pivot also we can achieve

**Sample Data**

```
Declare @Table1 TABLE 
    (inv_num varchar(6), scn int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (inv_num, scn)
VALUES
    ('MI1001', 160008),
    ('CI1002', 160008),
    ('VI1003', 160008)
;
```

**Script**

```
Select scn,[1] AS Misc,[2] As Cargo,[3] As Vessel  from (
select 
inv_num, 
scn,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY scn ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN 
        from @Table1)T
PIVOT (MAX(inv_num) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3]))PVT
```